# CNN LSTM keras for video classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have created a video dataset where each video have dimensions 5(frames) x 32(width) x 32(height) x 4 (channels). I'm trying to classify (binary classification) these videos using a CNN LSTM network but I'm confused about the input shape and how I should reshape my dataset to train the network.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1', input_shape=??))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='pool1')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='pool2')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='pool3')))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same', name='pool4')))


model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Am I missing anything in the model?

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to do video classification with CNN-LSTM also but it seems that my dataset doesn't fit into the RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input shape should be `(batch_size, time steps, height, width, channels)`. So it should be a 5 dimensional tensor.

Also, your `input_shape` argument should go like this. It should be an argument for the `TimeDistributed` layer not the `Conv2D` layer, because `TimeDistributed` is the first layer. Here, I'm showing what the input shape would be for a,

- batch of arbitray number of samples
- 5 time steps (video frames)
- 32vpixels tall (height)
- 32 pixels wide (width)
- 4 channels

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1'), input_shape=(5, 32, 32, 4)))
```